# 'Employee' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.ts(2693)

Tags: angular, typescript, api, interface

I am trying to create a variable of type Employee but it is showing an error of 'Employee' only refers to a type but is being used as a value here. ts(2693).

My show-api.ts code:-

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';

interface Employee {
    Id: String;
    EmployeeName: String;
    StartTimeUtc: String;
    EndTimeUtc: String;
    EntryNotes: String;
    DeletedOn: String;
}


@Component({
selector: 'app-show-api',
templateUrl: './show-api.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./show-api.component.css']
})


export class ShowApiComponent implements OnInit {

li:any;
lis: any=[];


constructor(private http : HttpClient){
    
}

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.http.get('Api of my JSON file')
    .subscribe(Response => {

    
    if(Response){
        hideloader();
    }

    **employee: Employee[]=Response**;


    
    });
    function hideloader(){
    document.getElementById('loading')!.style.display = 'none';}
}}
```

data from API

```
[

{"Id": "aa",
"EmployeeName": "bb",
"StarTimeUtc": "cc",
"EndTimeUtc": "dd",
"EntryNotes": "ee",
"DeletedOn": null },

{"Id": "ff",
"EmployeeName": "gg",
"StarTimeUtc": "hh",
"EndTimeUtc": "ii",
"EntryNotes": "jj",
"DeletedOn": null },

]
```

Also, if this is not solvable, please tell me an alternative way to get data from JSON file.

Comment: Are you sure that your api response is like you pasted? The part: `this.li=Response; this.lis=this.li.list;` suggests that your `Response` is an object (with a key `list` among others), and you're expecting `Reponse` to be an array of `Employee` types?

Comment: sorry for that...Please ignore that line 
And the API Response is correct as I have pasted it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are not declaring the variable in the right way nor mapping `Response` to your interface.

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.http.get('Api of my JSON file')
    .subscribe(Response => {

    
    if(Response){
        hideloader();
    }

    //oldCode -> **employee: Employee[]=Response**;
    /* New code */ const employee: Employee[] = Response as Employee[];
    
    });
    function hideloader(){
    document.getElementById('loading')!.style.display = 'none';}
}}
```